# Should I consider a bad practice doing blocking I/O during the application bootstrap? (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, bootstrapping

Consider I'm bootstraping a simple application (ie. `node server.js`), with the following **pseudo-code**:

```
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var router = require('function-that-handles-requests.js');
// ie, an express app

var routes = '/path/where/routes/are/stored';

fs.readdirSync( routes ).forEach(function( file ){
  var url = path.basename( file );
  var handler = require( path.resolve(routes, file) );

  router.useOrAddRouteOrWhatever( url, handler );

  // a real-world implementation should recurse sub-directories too
});

var server = http.createServer( router ).listen( /* ... */ );
```

### Should I consider a bad practice doing that blocking I/O?

Comment: I don't think so, this will blocking but while starting the server, which will be just once, In my opinion Bad practice will be if you are doing a blocking call while sending some `response` to a particular request

Comment: Your opinion matches mine, but I was wondering if someone can share some extra resources to endorse our thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, definitely not. The server hasn't started yet. This is, in fact, a common practice.

(the answer is this simple)

Comment: Your opinion matches mine, but I was wondering if there is some reliable resource (other than the pure logic) that supports our thoughts.

Comment: Well, Mritunjay and Marlon have more than 12000 StackOverflow points.  Does that count?  :-)